# page footer not set to bottom of pages in stimulsoft

Tags: reporting, stimulsoft

I designed a simple report using Stimulsoft report and put page footer on it,
but page footer is not set to bottom of pages.
Footer is placed all over the page. As if there was a constant distance between the footer and the last element of the page why?

Here is my report file  : https://forum.stimulsoft.com/download/file.php?id=21789

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not only a link.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you use the WebViewer to display the report.
You incorrectly placed the text (directly on the page) and when rendering it expands and goes beyond the bottom of the page.
But the browser stretches the table to display all the text, and PageFooter is appearing in the middle of the text.

Text that is placed directly on the page is a static object that is repeated on each page.
If you want the long text to break into pages - you need to put it on a DataBand.

Please check the modified report template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StiSerializer version="1.02" type="Net" application="StiReport">
  <Dictionary Ref="1" type="Dictionary" isKey="true">
    <BusinessObjects isList="true" count="0" />
    <Databases isList="true" count="0" />
    <DataSources isList="true" count="0" />
    <Relations isList="true" count="0" />
    <Report isRef="0" />
    <Resources isList="true" count="0" />
    <Variables isList="true" count="0" />
  </Dictionary>
  <EngineVersion>EngineV2</EngineVersion>
  <GlobalizationStrings isList="true" count="0" />
  <MetaTags isList="true" count="0" />
  <Pages isList="true" count="1">
    <Page1 Ref="2" type="Page" isKey="true">
      <Border>None;Black;2;Solid;False;4;Black</Border>
      <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
      <Components isList="true" count="3">
        <PageFooterBand1 Ref="3" type="PageFooterBand" isKey="true">
          <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
          <ClientRectangle>0,24.1,19.6,1.8</ClientRectangle>
          <Components isList="true" count="1">
            <Text2 Ref="4" type="Text" isKey="true">
              <Border>All;Black;2;Solid;False;4;Black</Border>
              <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
              <ClientRectangle>4.8,0.3,12.6,1.2</ClientRectangle>
              <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
              <Font>Microsoft Sans Serif,18,Bold</Font>
              <HorAlignment>Center</HorAlignment>
              <Margins>0,0,0,0</Margins>
              <Name>Text2</Name>
              <Page isRef="2" />
              <Parent isRef="3" />
              <Text>Footer Page</Text>
              <TextBrush>Black</TextBrush>
              <Type>Expression</Type>
              <VertAlignment>Center</VertAlignment>
            </Text2>
          </Components>
          <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
          <Name>PageFooterBand1</Name>
          <Page isRef="2" />
          <Parent isRef="2" />
        </PageFooterBand1>
        <ReportTitleBand1 Ref="5" type="ReportTitleBand" isKey="true">
          <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
          <ClientRectangle>0,0.4,19.6,0.2</ClientRectangle>
          <Components isList="true" count="0" />
          <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
          <Name>ReportTitleBand1</Name>
          <Page isRef="2" />
          <Parent isRef="2" />
        </ReportTitleBand1>
        <DataBand1 Ref="6" type="DataBand" isKey="true">
          <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
          <CanBreak>True</CanBreak>
          <ClientRectangle>0,1.4,19.6,15.4</ClientRectangle>
          <Components isList="true" count="1">
            <Text1 Ref="7" type="Text" isKey="true">
              <Border>None;Black;2;Solid;False;4;Black</Border>
              <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
              <CanBreak>True</CanBreak>
              <CanGrow>True</CanGrow>
              <ClientRectangle>1,1.8,17.6,13.4</ClientRectangle>
              <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
              <Font>Microsoft Sans Serif,9,Bold</Font>
              <GrowToHeight>True</GrowToHeight>
              <HorAlignment>Center</HorAlignment>
              <Margins>0,0,0,0</Margins>
              <Name>Text1</Name>
              <Page isRef="2" />
              <Parent isRef="6" />
              <Text>ghgk
hj
mlm
gg
dd
ghgk
hj
mlm
gg
dd
ghgk
hj
mlm
gg
mlm
gg
dd
ghgk
hj
mlm
gg
dd
ghgk
hj
mlm
gg
dd
ghgk
hj
mlm
gg
dd
mlm
gg
dd
ghgk
hj
mlm
gg
mlm
mlm
gg
dd
ghgk
hj
mlm
gg
mlm
mlm
gg
dd
ghgk
hj
mlm
gg
mlm
111111111111
22222222222
33333333333
gg
dd
ghgk
hj
mlm
gg
mlm
gg
dd
ghgk
hj
mlm
gg
dd</Text>
              <TextBrush>Black</TextBrush>
              <TextOptions>,,,,WordWrap=True,A=0</TextOptions>
              <Type>Expression</Type>
              <VertAlignment>Center</VertAlignment>
            </Text1>
          </Components>
          <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
          <Filters isList="true" count="0" />
          <Name>DataBand1</Name>
          <Page isRef="2" />
          <Parent isRef="2" />
          <Sort isList="true" count="0" />
        </DataBand1>
      </Components>
      <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
      <Guid>09e02623e900473caee1145d795b6025</Guid>
      <Margins>1,1,1,1</Margins>
      <Name>Page1</Name>
      <PageHeight>27.9</PageHeight>
      <PageWidth>21.6</PageWidth>
      <PaperSize>Letter</PaperSize>
      <Report isRef="0" />
      <Watermark Ref="8" type="Stimulsoft.Report.Components.StiWatermark" isKey="true">
        <Font>Arial,100</Font>
        <TextBrush>[50:0:0:0]</TextBrush>
      </Watermark>
    </Page1>
  </Pages>
  <PrinterSettings Ref="9" type="Stimulsoft.Report.Print.StiPrinterSettings" isKey="true" />
  <ReferencedAssemblies isList="true" count="8">
    <value>System.Dll</value>
    <value>System.Drawing.Dll</value>
    <value>System.Windows.Forms.Dll</value>
    <value>System.Data.Dll</value>
    <value>System.Xml.Dll</value>
    <value>Stimulsoft.Controls.Dll</value>
    <value>Stimulsoft.Base.Dll</value>
    <value>Stimulsoft.Report.Dll</value>
  </ReferencedAssemblies>
  <ReportAlias>Report</ReportAlias>
  <ReportChanged>11/1/2017 12:51:33 PM</ReportChanged>
  <ReportCreated>9/6/2017 10:47:11 PM</ReportCreated>
  <ReportFile>Report.mrt</ReportFile>
  <ReportGuid>9d35bfde4fd44c1c88bc4f2caecb5da5</ReportGuid>
  <ReportImage isNull="true" />
  <ReportName>Report</ReportName>
  <ReportUnit>Centimeters</ReportUnit>
  <ReportVersion>2017.2.3.0</ReportVersion>
  <Script>using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using Stimulsoft.Controls;
using Stimulsoft.Base.Drawing;
using Stimulsoft.Report;
using Stimulsoft.Report.Dialogs;
using Stimulsoft.Report.Components;

namespace Reports
{
    public class Report : Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport
    {
        public Report()        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region StiReport Designer generated code - do not modify
        #endregion StiReport Designer generated code - do not modify
    }
}
</Script>
  <ScriptLanguage>CSharp</ScriptLanguage>
  <Styles isList="true" count="0" />
</StiSerializer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Insert tab and select `Page Footer`
[image]